# pandas groupby apply is taking forever

Tags: python, pandas, performance, apply

I'm trying to identify individuals in a large dataframe with 5 different interviews (variable `V1016`), and store it in the variable `KeyInd`. The rows that has same values for `KeyDom` and `nascimento` belongs to the same person.

This is a sample of the dataframe:

| V1016 | V2009 | V2007 | keyDom | keyInd | nascimento |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 64 | 1 | 11000003417 | 0 | 1 - 7/11/1953 |
| 1 | 37 | 2 | 11000003417 | 0 | 2 - 22/12/1980 |
| 1 | 14 | 2 | 11000003417 | 0 | 2 - 1/11/2003 |
| 2 | 64 | 1 | 11000003417 | 0 | 1 - 7/11/1953 |
| 2 | 37 | 2 | 11000003417 | 0 | 2 - 22/12/1980 |
| 2 | 14 | 2 | 11000003417 | 0 | 2 - 1/11/2003 |
| 3 | 65 | 1 | 11000003417 | 0 | 1 - 7/11/1953 |
| 3 | 37 | 2 | 11000003417 | 0 | 2 - 22/12/1980 |
| 3 | 15 | 2 | 11000003417 | 0 | 2 - 1/11/2003 |

I'm trying to pass this function using `groupby.apply`:

```
def identifica_pessoas(df):
    pessoas = df[df['V1016'] == 1]['nascimento'].tolist()
    rodadas = list(range(1, 6))
    for rodada in rodadas:
        row = df[df.V1016 == rodada]
        for i in range(len(pessoas)):
            try:
                indice = [index for index, value in enumerate(pessoas) if value == row.nascimento.iloc[i]][0]
                row.keyInd.iloc[i] = row.keyDom.iloc[i] + str(indice)
            except:
                pass
        df[df.V1016 == rodada] = row
    return df
```

The code to pass the function is as follows:

```
painel7_filtrado = painel7.groupby('keyDom').apply(identifica_pessoas)
```

The result I'm expecting is like:

| V1016 | V2009 | V2007 | keyDom | keyInd | nascimento |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 64 | 1 | 11000003417 | 110000034170 | 1 - 7/11/1953 |
| 1 | 37 | 2 | 11000003417 | 110000034171 | 2 - 22/12/1980 |
| 1 | 14 | 2 | 11000003417 | 110000034172 | 2 - 1/11/2003 |
| 2 | 64 | 1 | 11000003417 | 110000034170 | 1 - 7/11/1953 |
| 2 | 37 | 2 | 11000003417 | 110000034171 | 2 - 22/12/1980 |
| 2 | 14 | 2 | 11000003417 | 110000034172 | 2 - 1/11/2003 |
| 3 | 65 | 1 | 11000003417 | 110000034170 | 1 - 7/11/1953 |
| 3 | 37 | 2 | 11000003417 | 110000034171 | 2 - 22/12/1980 |
| 3 | 15 | 2 | 11000003417 | 110000034172 | 2 - 1/11/2003 |

But it's taking hours to process. How can I make this code faster?

Comment: Would you provide a sample dataframe with expected outputs? In the lambda you have many operations working on the whole dataframe in the method, which is occurring for each row. For example: `pessoas = df[df['V1016'] == 1]['nascimento'].tolist()` So I would suggest doing this step before and passing the pre-computed list into the lambda.

Comment: I've just added a sample dataframe, thank you. and I'm also working in your tip to compute the list outside the lambda function.

Comment: Ian's comment made me solve the problem with a different aproach. I made a dataframe with all individuals in the first interview than i used `merge` with the main dataframe. Worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with a different aproach. I created another dataframe with all individuals in the first interview with an ID than i used `merge` with the main dataframe. Worked just fine.